# Resizing image with HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to size an image with canvas. My goal is to have an image of dimensions A x B sized to M x N without changing proportions - like CSS contain. For example, if the source image is 1000x1000 and the destination is 400x300, it should cut off a piece 100 pixels toll at the bottom, and that should correspond to 250 pixels in the source image.

My code is below:

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const img = new Image();
img.src = promotedImage;
const FINAL_WIDTH = 400;
const FINAL_HEIGHT = 250;
const width = img.width;
const height = img.height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, FINAL_WIDTH, FINAL_HEIGHT);
const finalImage = b64toFile(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg"));
```

This is not working, like I want to, though. I am obviously using drawImage incorrectly. For me, if copies source to destination without sizing.

Is this because I need to size (change dimensions) for canvas prior to drawing? Please advise.

I have also tried something like [Mozilla image upload](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/). It does even scale the image, but it does not crop. Plus, it sizes a source square to the smaller target side, instead of clipping it.

Comment: The default canvas is usually sized at 300x150. Yes, you'll need to set the `width` and `height` attributes to change this. (These are not the same as the `width` and `height` CSS styles.) Note that this may only be part of your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting an image source is asynchronous, can be very fast, but often not fast enough to keep up with still-running code. Generally, to make them work reliably, you set an `onload` handler first and then set `src`. The canvas element defaults to 300x150 so would also need to be sized. (Canvas obeys CORS. `.crossOrigin = ''` sets us as anonymous and imgur has a permissive CORS policy. We wouldn't be able to convert the canvas to an image while using a third-party image in this snippet otherwise.)

```js
const MAX_WIDTH = 400;
const MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
const img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = '';
img.onload = () => {
  const wRatio = MAX_WIDTH / img.width;
  const hRatio = MAX_HEIGHT / img.height;
  var width, height;
  if(wRatio > hRatio) {
    width = MAX_WIDTH;
    height = wRatio * img.height;
  }
  else {
    width = hRatio * img.width;
    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
  }
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  //const finalImage = b64toFile(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg"));
  const imgElement = document.createElement('img');
  imgElement.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
  document.body.appendChild(imgElement);
};
img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/TMeawxt.jpeg';
```

```css
img { border: 1px solid red; }
```

Comment: Your example does NOT keep proportions, though. It stretches the image.

Comment: This one fits the image inside, but there is a free/unused space on the side then. I guess might depend on dimensions. However swapping the sign `<` for `>` fixes the problem, for me. Still needs a little more testing. Thank you.

Comment: @IgorShmukler Unless the canvas has exactly the same aspect ratio as the original image, there's always going to be either whitespace or clipping. I've made adjustments so the canvas' aspect ratio is adjusted to match that of the image. The `<`/`>` controls whether the sizing is to fit or to cover.